# Как отформатировать строку?

Tags: javascript

Получаю данные из `<input type="text">`, как сделать валидацию (сохранить строку как текст, игнорируя теги, код) получаемой строки, чтобы отправить на сервер?
Получаю `typeof` значения из `input`, даже если там `<script>...</script>` - возвращает `string`. Но сервер отказывается принимать такую "строку".

Comment: Так это и есть string. Как html ее может только браузер воспринимать. Можно валидировать на теги и запрещать. Посмотрите на https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: @DStrokov, спасибо, разобрался)